# Ideal generated by its uniformiser

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given $A$ a Dedekind ring, with $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$.

I want to understant why $\operatorname{Cl}(X)=\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ (Hartshorne page 132 example 6.3.1).

For that I need to verify that for all $\mathfrak{p}$ prime ideal of $A$, $\mathfrak{p}$ is principal iff $V(\mathfrak{p})=Y$ (the closed subscheme of $X$ associated to $\mathfrak{p}$) is principal.

It is clear to me that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is principal with $\mathfrak{p}=fA$ then $V(\mathfrak{p})$ is principal with $V(\mathfrak{p})=(f)$.

I don't see why the converse is true: taking $f\in A$ with $V(\mathfrak{p})=(f)$ then (because $v_Y(f)=1$) we have $f\in\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ and $f\notin(\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p})^2$. As $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is regular of dimension 1 (DVR) one has $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}=fA_\mathfrak{p}$. I can deduce that $f\in\mathfrak{p}$ but not that $fA=\mathfrak{p}$. I don't used that for the other prime $Y'=V(\mathfrak{q})$ one has $V_{Y'}(f)=0$ that if $f\notin\mathfrak{q}$, but how? I feel I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: I think you should clarify your notation first. What do you mean by a closed subscheme to be principal? Also, what do you mean by $V(p) = (f)$?

Comment: I mean that $Y$ is the divisor associated to one $f\in K(X)^*$ (Hartshorne definition page 131). By $V(\mathfrak{p})=(f)$ I mean that the closed subscheme $V(p)=\{\mathfrak{p}\}$ is the divisor associated to $f\in K(X)^*$.

Comment: As both $(f)$ and $p$ are $p$-primary, it suffices to check equality locally. But I still don’t follow your notation. Where in Hartshorne’n book does he use your notation of $V(p) = (f)$?

Comment: For $V(\mathfrak{p})$ Hartshorne define it page 70

Comment: So I see why $(f)$ is primary: writing $fA=\prod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ one has $f\in\mathfrak{p}_i$ for all $i$. As $f\notin \mathfrak{q}$ for $\mathfrak{q}\neq\mathfrak{p}$ the only prime in the decomposition of $fA$ is $\mathfrak{p}$ so $fA=\mathfrak{p}^e$ so $\sqrt{fA}=\mathfrak{p}$ wich is maximal so $fA$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary

Comment: I see how to conclude directly: if one has $fA=\mathfrak{p}^e$ with $e\geqslant 2$ then $f\in\mathfrak{p}^2$ so $f\in\mathfrak{p}^2A_\mathfrak{p}$ which is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I understand your argument "it suffices to check equality locally": two $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal $\mathfrak{q}_1$ and $\mathfrak{q}_2$, they are equals iff they are equals in $A_\mathfrak{p}$: in general when writing decomposition $\mathfrak{q}_i=\prod_j \mathfrak{p_j}^{e_{i,j}}$ localization in $A_\mathfrak{p_{j_0}}$ cut of all the factors in decomposition which are not $\mathfrak{p_{j_0}}$